# A way to compare generics in Swift only if they conform to Equatable

Tags: swift, generics, equatable, conform

Wondering if there's a good way to do this or not:

I have a `@propertyWrapper` named "Enhanced" that I use. I use the `wrappedValue.set` to do some actions, and I would also like to do some further actions if the property is Equatable.

Currently, the code looks like this:

```
@propertyWrapper
class Enhanced<T: Equatable>: Codable
{
    private var value: T
    var projectedValue: Enhanced<T> { self }

    var wrappedValue: T
    {
        get { value }
        set { set(newValue, notify: nil) }
    }
    
    func set(_ proposedValue: T, notify: Bool?)
    {
        let oldValue = value
        let newValue = proposedValue
        let changed = newValue != oldValue

        if changed { /* more magic here */ }

        value = newValue
    }
}
```

Now I would like to remove the `Equatable` conformance over the generic `T`, but still be able to compare the old and new values IF the generic T conforms to Equatable.

I've tried a handful of techniques, all of which dead end somewhere. My latest was this:

```
        let changed: Bool
        switch T.self
        {
        case let equatableType as any Equatable.Type:
            if
                let oldEquatableValue = oldValue as? any Equatable,
                let newEquatableValue = newValue as? any Equatable
            {
                changed = newEquatableValue != oldEquatableValue
            }
        default:
            changed = true
        }
```

...but the error is an understandable `Binary operator '!=' cannot be applied to two 'any Equatable' operands`.

I tried different patterns to cast the generic type T into an Equatable and silently fail if the generic does not conform, but even if they do, the resulting "cast" types I get back aren't equatable themselves.

Any revelations to the proper pattern would be great!

Comment: To be able to use the `==` or `!=` operator the type must conform to `Equatable`, there is no workaround.

Comment: You don't have the "Equatable conformance over the whole class", if you did, it would look like this: `class Enhanced<T: Equatable>: Codable, Equatable`
But you have the Equatable conformance of `T`, which is absolutely good way of doing it. And it's better to leave it that way. If any class does not conform to `Equatable`, it's easy to make it conform. In worst case your equatable can return `false` unless they are the same object: `static func == (lhs: ..., rhs: ...) -> Bool { return lhs === rhs }` which would be the equivalent of your `default: changed = true`

Comment: Thanks akjndklskver, I corrected the question to clarify what actually has the `Equatable` conformance. I believe the `default:` case will be fine, but it's the `changed = newEquatableValue != oldEquatableValue` line that is returning the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some deep web-sleuthing, I came across a snippet of code that does the magic I need:

```
private extension Equatable
{
    func isEqualTo(_ rhs: Any) -> Bool
    {
        if let castRHS = rhs as? Self
        {
            return self == castRHS
        }
        else
        {
            return false
        }
    }
}
```

(HT to neonichu/equalizer.swift on GitHub)

With this bit of pseudo type-erasure, I can make this work:

```
let changed: Bool
if let oldEquatableValue = oldValue as? any Equatable,
   let newEquatableValue = newValue as? any Equatable
{
    changed = oldEquatableValue.isEqualTo(newEquatableValue) == false
}
else
{
    changed = true
}
```

By using an extension on `Equatable` that does further casting of the values, this allows for these two values to be compared (and fail if they are not the same).

Hope this helps someone else!